# Image gallery for jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mobile, jquery-mobile, gallery

I would like to use a jQuery mobile gallery plugin on my mobile app. What I would like to find is one that has all the images on one line with swipe functionality.

I have tried PhotoSwipe and some other image galleries, but they all open images on a separate page, without the possibility to swipe on thumbnails.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a suitable plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://swipejs.com/

People have successfully used it with jQuery Mobile.

You can also ask at the forums here if you get stuck: http://forum.jquery.com/jquery-mobile